# Inject Factory into Factory

Tags: angularjs, factory

How do you make a factory available from another factory? Using the below the console tells me there is an error (injector:unpr).

```
angular.module( 'fb.services', [] ).factory( 'getQueryString', function() {
    return { call: function( qs ) {
        var result = {}, queryString = qs.substring( 1 ), re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;
        while ( m = re.exec( queryString ) )
            result[decodeURIComponent( m[1] )] = decodeURIComponent( m[2] );
        return result;
    }}
});

angular.module( 'fb.services', ['fb.services'] ).factory( 'getReferrer', function( getQueryString ) {
        var qry = getQueryString.call( 'query=string&this=that' );
        // fails to find getQueryString
});
```

Comment: You define fb.services twice?!

Comment: Can you give some further information on your comment?

Comment: The dependency list inside `[]` should not contain `fb.services`. You cannot depend upon self.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
angular.module( 'fb.services').factory( 'getReferrer',['getQueryString', function( getQueryString ) {
        var qry = getQueryString.call( 'query=string&this=that' );
        // fails to find getQueryString
}]);
```

When you use the second argument in the module declaration `angular.module( 'fb.services','fb.services'] )` it means you are redefining/defining the module again with new dependencies, which means anything registered previously are lost.

After you have defined your module, you just access it by doing `angular.module( 'fb.services')` *(omit second argument, so it becomes a getter of the module that has been already defined)*

Also see [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) and [annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)